# How to pass an output xmi/cas to UIMA Ruta engine?

Tags: java, ruta

I hava a cas run on an AnalysisEngine (say AE1) to which we have injected some annotations in java, say JI1 (We have overloaded the default process method). So, how do i use my AE created from JAVA in ruta workbench ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your own Java analysis engines with the EXEC action. Examples from the [documentation](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.overview.examples):

```
ENGINE utils.Modifier;
Date{-> DEL};
MoneyAmount{-> REPLACE("<MoneyAmount/>")};
Document{-> COLOR(Headline, "green")};
Document{-> EXEC(Modifier)};
```

or

```
UIMAFIT my.package.impl.MyAnalysisEngine;
Document{-> EXEC(MyAnalysisEngine, {MyType1, MyType2})};
```

The preferred approach depends on the kind of your AE and if there is a description. In any case, the implementation of the AE needs to be on the classpath of the project.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: Thanks! I understand that. But I don't want to execute the first engine while running the second script. I already have the output cas/xmi. W.r.t your reply, I haven't tried the second method so far. We used 'rutaEngine.process(javaOutputCas)' and achieved what I wanted. I assume SimplePipeline.runPipeline(javaOutputCas, rutaEngine) should also work. By doing so, I didn't need to run the java engine again. Is there a way to do the same in Ruta itself(To pass the already created output Xmi to another Engine)?

Comment: By uín Ruta, do you mean the UIMA Ruta Workbench? If yes, then you can simply put the xmi in the input folder.